# All array elements have same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following is my JavaScript code:

```js
var enddate, finaldate, startyear, endyear, i;
startyear = 2010;
endyear = 2011;
enddate = new Date(endyear, 11, 31)
finaldate = new Date(enddate)
var a = [];
j = 0;
enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + 6)
for (i = new Date(startyear, 0, 1); i <= enddate; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 6)) {
    if (i > finaldate) {
        console.log(finaldate);
    } else {
        console.log("Value of i: " + i);
        a.push(i);

        console.log(a[j++]);
    }
}

for (var k = 0; k <= a.length; k++) {
    console.log(a[k])
}
```

The statement `console.log("Value of i: " +i);` prints the correct values in console but when I try printing the values of an array `a` at the end, it gives me ALL the values as *Mon Jan 09 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)*, cannot understand why would this happen.

Comment: It's happening because you have a for loop that's iterating over date objects, and `i` is a global reference to an object that you keep changing. To be clearer, you're not pushing unique values to the array, but the same reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new date object inside the loop. When using `.push()` on an array in javascript, the objects and arrays are pushed by reference. Built-in types like numbers are pushed as a copy.

```js
var enddate, finaldate, startyear, endyear, i;
startyear = 2010;
endyear = 2011;
enddate = new Date(endyear, 11, 31)
finaldate = new Date(enddate)
var a = [];
j = 0;
enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + 6)
for (i = new Date(startyear, 0, 1); i <= enddate; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 6)) {
    if (i > finaldate) {
        console.log(finaldate);
    } else {
        console.log("Value of i: " + i);
        var m = new Date(i);
        a.push(m);

        console.log(a[j++]);
    }

}


for (var k = 0; k <= a.length; k++) {

    console.log(a[k])
}
```

Comment: `console.log(a[j++]);` give the "correct " date, because as all the items of `a` are references to `i`, it displays the last value of `i`

Comment: and for the same reason all the values are "jan 9 2012", which it is the last value assigned to `i` before exit the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You create a date object at the start of the loop and store a reference to it in `i`.

Each time you go around the loop, you copy that reference into the array and modify the value of the date object.

You end up with an array containing a bunch of references to the same date object which is set to the final value you set it to.

You need to create a new date object each time you go around the loop.

e.g.

```
a.push(new Date(i));
```

Comment: On line 16, why does "console.log(a[j++]);" give the correct dates?

Comment: okay, that given solution worked but I am still unclear as to why the date being stored in array "a" is "jan 9 2012" my end date according to code should be maximum "jan 06 2012"

Comment: Because "jan 9 2012" is the last value assigned to `i` before exit the for loop

Comment: @Ketcomp — `console.log(a[j++]);` works because you are testing inside the original loop, so you are testing before you assign the new value.